# Wrong COUNT() from MySQL in some but not all of the groupings

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of values in a group of matching values. The first query does the count, the second lists the output of the data itself. Please note the count doesn't always match the output of the second query. I'm not sure why this error is occurring or how to fix it. I suspect the problem is with the GROUP BY but after trying many versions of it I don't have a solution.

```
SELECT CONCAT(date_format(timestamp,'%H'),':',LPAD(MINUTE(
       FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/300)*300)),2,0)) AS hrmn,
                
       COUNT(CONCAT(date_format(timestamp,'%H'),':',LPAD(MINUTE(
       FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/300)*300)),2,0))) AS hrmncount
       
  FROM TimeLog
 WHERE netID = 3646
 GROUP BY CONCAT(date_format(timestamp,'%H'),':',LPAD(MINUTE(
          FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/300)*300)),2,0))
;
            
SELECT CONCAT(date_format(timestamp,'%H'),':',LPAD(MINUTE(
       FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/300)*300)),2,0)) AS hrmn
       
  FROM TimeLog
 WHERE netID = 3646
 GROUP BY timestamp
 ORDER BY hrmn ASC
;
```

This is the output of the first query:

```
hrmn   hrmncount
00:50  2
01:00  10
01:05  9 
01:10  12
01:15  5
01:20  7
01:25  6
01:30  3
01:35  1
```

But this is the output from the second, which shows that the first query is counting wrong in the 00:50, 01:10 and 01:20 values.

```
hrmn
00:50
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:00
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:05
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:10
01:15
01:15
01:15
01:15
01:15
01:20
01:20
01:20
01:20
01:20
01:20
01:20
01:25
01:25
01:25
01:25
01:25
01:25
01:30
01:30
01:30
01:35
```

Comment: After some additional digging I found a record in the DB or actually two records with identical timestamps to the millisecond and the same value of callsign. Both are legitimate entries so now I need to figure  out why MySQL is only showing me one of those two records. The additional count differences were found do to an invalid callsign, which I now test for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track the root of the problem down to the GROUP BY in the SQL code. It wasn't needed, and by removing it all the records including the duplicate by time were exposed.
I should have seen this earlier but sometimes you get blind to the obvious.